# Me muestra la tabla con console.table separada con uso de forEach

Tags: javascript

Tengo una formula para añadirle el 50 % a los números de un array usando un forEach pero cuando los muestro con tablas por consola me las muestra por separado.

Este es el array:

```
let NumerosA = [4,6,8,5];
```

y esta es la función anónima:

```js
let numerosA = [4,6,8,5];

let porcentaje = prompt("Indica el procentaje");


const Incrementar = ( arr, porcentaje ) => {
    
    arr.forEach((elemento, index) => {
      let formula = elemento + (porcentaje / 100 * elemento);
      let tabla = [formula];
      console.table(tabla);
    });
}

Incrementar(numerosA, porcentaje);
```

No entiendo porque me muestra varias tablas en vez de mostrarme una única tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por qué `console.table()` te muestra un objeto de datos en una tabla , pero cada ves que iteras y haces el console.table se genera una nueva tabla con cada iteracion.
Prueba almacenar toda la data que necesitas y luego cuando termina el forEach recién haces el consolé.table

Comment: Muchas gracias! funcionó.